# mkdir from MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

How do I create a directory from MacVim?

I can use `:e` to create file, but I am struggling to find out how to create a directory.

I have tried `mkdir` from `:`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute any shell command with ! like this:

```
:!mkdir YOURDIR
```

Read more with

```
 :help !
```

Comment: And if you do it often, `:cmap md !mkdir`

Comment: `:mkdir -p %:h` is also a handy shorthand to create any directories necessary to save the current file (e.g. after you `:e foo/bar/baz` when `foo/` or `foo/bar/` may not yet exist). See the *mkdir(1)* manpage for `-p` and `:help %:h` for the modifier.

Comment: Thanks guys! Is there any way to have that command's path start at your project's root directory?

Answer (score 5):

There is a native `vim` function `mkdir()`.

Example:

```
:call mkdir("/path/to/your/dir", "p", 0700)
```

Type `:help mkdir()` to read more.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go for any scripted usage.